# iPhone AVAudioRecorder Guide?

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or discussion that provides a clear-cut, full explanation of how to use the AVAudioRecorder method of recording audio in iPhone apps? Although I'm new to iPhone programming in general, I do have a basic understanding and yet all my attempts to use AVAudioRecorder have failed miserable. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code and documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html). You can fill in the blanks with searches  here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+audio+playing+recording). If you haven't started with Audio, it's best to look at the Apple docs and example code first. Then have a look at other sources. This is where a good book on iPhone development comes in.

Comment: Thanks! This led me to an adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use AVAudioRecorder you first need to enable the AVAudioSession and init and start AVAudioRecorder, here's my example of how to set everything up and measure the level of "loudness" for instance  http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/04/15/swift-how-to-get-decibels/